# ttyS0: 1 input overrun(s) using python pexpect

Tags: console, embedded-linux, pexpect

I am getting this issue regularly. I am using pexpect session to connect with embedded device console.
  ttyS0: 1 input overrun(s)

Can anyone suggest a solution to resolve this issue ? 
Is there any alternative library to slow down of sending a command, So that i can reduce this issue.

Comment: What Embedded Linux platform are you using?